# Check UserRole and set Permission in Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Suppose I have a actionlink in the layout, which I want to show, if the logged-in user is in either of the two roles "Manager" or "Salesperson", then how do I do that?
What I have been doing is as follows:-

```
@if((User.IsInRole("Manager"))||(User.IsInRole("Salesperson")))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Sales Reports", "SalesReports", "Reports")
}
```

Unfortunately, the above line of code is not working. The link "Sales Reports" is not visible to users with role "Salesperson".
I want to make the link "Sales Reports" visible only to users in "Manager" role or in "Salesperson" role. Kindly advise how to go about it?
Thank You.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? If you put a breakpoint to your if and log in with a Salesperson, what to you see? Is it even reaching the if?

Comment: Yes it hits the breakpoint when logged in with users in both the Roles. If logged in with Manager Role, it gets inside the if-block, but with Salesperson role it doesnt.

Comment: Can you view the role your user has while you debug your code? Can you get the role name? Is it "Salesperson"?

Comment: Yes i do get the role as well. If I use one of the two roles then it works fine, but using the 2 conditions together i.e. `((User.IsInRole("Manager"))||(User.IsInRole("Salesperson")))` creates the problem.

Comment: If you try with inverted order (first "Salesperson", then "Manager"), then what is working? Manager or Salesperson?

Comment: The one that I'm keeping first..works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC way of doing things rolebased is by using [Authorize] attribute for the action or controller. You can then say whch roles are granted as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Manager,Salesperson")]
```

You can perhaps create a partial view which contains these actions and show the one based on the users role.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Manager,Salesperson")]
public ActionResult NavigationLinks()
{
     return View("PATH TO PARTIAL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work with your line. May be you've made a mistake in word "Salesperson"?

I'd also advice to move this logic to controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
  bool isAllowed = User.IsInRole("Manager")||User.IsInRole("Salesperson");
  ViewBag.isAllowed = isAllowed;

  ...
  return View();
}
```

Than in your View:

```
@if((bool)ViewBag.isAllowed)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Sales Reports", "SalesReports", "Reports")
}
```

Comment: I've rechecked and i believe there are no spelling mistakes. What I am trying to do is set some permissions on the landing page depending on the UserRole  after any user logs in. I am a bit confused about where to place this ActionResult which you've mentioned.

Comment: @aritra You don't need separate ActionResult. I mean that you may add those two lines of code (ViewBag) in ActionResult which corresponds with your View, where you want to handle permission.

Comment: Actually, I am having Actionlinks in my Layout as well. Incase if I want to restrict permission for those ActionLinks in the layout, then in which Controller should I add the above mentioned logic? This is where I am getting confused. I hope I make sense to you @Andrey.